# Play .gif animation in dynamic x,y - Android

Tags: java, android, animation, gif

I'm trying to play gif animations on certain x,y coordinates.
i tried using the Movie class, but sadly most gif animations plays wired and not smooth enough.
In the Movie class i could simply set x,y coordinates of where i want my movie to be,
Now i want to use the GifDecoder class, but have no idea how to play it in dynamic x,y coordinates which changes all the time, and also make it seem smooth.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [GifDecoder](http://www.gif4j.com/java-api-pro/com/gif4j/GifDecoder.html), then [here](http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/help/gifdecoder.html) are some resources that I think might help you.

A tutorial can be found [here](http://droid-blog.net/2011/10/15/tutorial-how-to-play-animated-gifs-in-android-%E2%80%93-part-2/).

Comment: i found a way to do what i want, but there's a problem. the GifDecoder class for some reason, it's getFrameCount() function always returns 0. I've tried it with several gif files and the results remain the same. any suggestions?

Comment: Why would you use getFrameCount?

Comment: to know how much frames the gif file contains and play it frame by frame so when it comes to the end it will loop

Comment: I'm not sure but I think getFrameCount returns the frame that it's currently displaying.